# importing filename and using regex to change the filename and save back

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have files with filenames as "lsud-ifgufib-1234568789.png" I want to rename this file as digits only which are followed by last "-" and then save them back in the folder.

Basically I want the final filename to be the digits that are followed by "-".

```
~  path = 'C:/Users/abc/downloads'
  for filename in os.listdir(path):
      r = re.compile("(\d+)")
      newlist = filter(r.match, filename) 
      print(newlist)
```

~
How do I proceed further?

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- You want to rename files if the file has a hyphen before the number.
- The file may or may not have an extention.
- If the file has an extention, preserve it.

Then would you please try the following:

```
import re, os

path = 'C:/Users/abc/downloads'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    m = re.search(r'.*-(\d+.*)', filename)
    if m:
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, filename), os.path.join(path, m.group(1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a `regex` search followed by a path join:

```py
import re
import os

path = 'C:/Users/abc/downloads'
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    os.rename(filename, os.path.join(path, re.search("\d+(?=\D+?$)", filename).group()))
```

Comment: this give me an error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: How about my edits?

Comment: Yes running it gives me :'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Do all of the files have that pattern in them? Can you post the output of the first few rows of `for filename in os.listdir(path): print(filename)`? Made some more edits to generalize to nonpng files as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import pathlib

fileName = "lsud-ifgufib-1234568789.png"
_extn = pathlib.Path(fileName).suffix

_digObj = re.compile(r'\d+')
digFileName = ''.join(_digObj.findall(fileName))

replFileName = digFileName + _extn
```